AWS RDS MySQL read replica's failover and standby instance's failover
This question is for AWS RDS MySQL
I have recently started studying RDS, trying to study from the documentation as well as other sources. For following scenario I am unable to understand certain concepts.
Please help me out with some explanations
Let's assume that I have a master instance A in a multi-AZ setup, thus I will have at least one standby instance (Let's say B) in another AZ.
Also I have a created a read replica C in the same AZ as A, and a standby instance (Let's say D) for read replica.
The replication between master A and standby B is synchronous for the reasons of not losing any transactions.
In this case, please correct me, the master A will be master for B and C, and C will be master for D.
First doubt
Now let's say there was an automatic failover on master A and thus, standby B will become new master.
Now my question is what will happen to C and D?
Will C be a read replica of the new failed over master B?
Will A become standby of B?
Second doubt
If I choose to promote C as new master, will original master A and it's standby start replication from new master C or they will not be useful anymore?
